# Why were there Sylvester Stallone movie references?

Tags: production, beverly-hills-cop-2

In [*Beverly Hills Cop II*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092644/?ref_=nv_sr_5), there are several references made about Sylvester Stallone's movies:

This image shows a movie poster of *Rambo* (a Sylvester Stallone film) in the background:

[image: Rambo]

This image shows a movie poster of *Cobra* (another Sylvester Stallone film) in the background:

[image: Cobra]

Near the end of the film, John Taggart says the following line:

> Fuck Rambo

Out of universe note:  [Brigitte Nielsen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000557/?ref_=tt_cl_t6) stars in the film.  She was married to Sylvester Stallone from 1984-1987.

**Why were the Sylvester Stallone references used?  Is this just a coincidence or did producers intentionally reference Stallone?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's a thumb in the eye to Stallone.

Apparently...Stallone was signed to play Axel Foley in the original *Beverley Hills Cop*...but rewrote the script to his own specs.

> Stallone reflected that when he first received the action/comedy script in the mail, he thought it was sent to the wrong house. The actor, who by 1983 had already written the first three Rocky movies and First Blood, re-wrote Beverly Hills Cop to better suit his strengths, making it into a pure action flick as it had been before Petrie Jr. took over script duties. In Stallone's ending, Axel drives a stolen Lamborghini towards a freight train being driven by the Big Bad.
>
> <sup>[MentalFloss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/60484/15-things-you-may-not-have-known-about-beverly-hills-cop)</sup>

....but it fell through...allegedly because of Orange Juice!

> The Hollywood legend is that Sylvester Stallone abandoned the project thanks to failed negotiations over what type of orange juice was to be kept in his trailer.
>
> The official explanation was that Stallone's script made the budget skyrocket, and Paramount did not want to spend all the extra money. **A majority of Stallone's script went into his 1986 movie Cobra, and as a nod to Stallone's involvement, Judge Reinhold's character Billy Rosewood has posters of both Cobra and Rambo in his room in Beverly Hills Cop II.**

Comment: Putting bananas in tail pipes is a much less expensive prospect for a film than stealing Lamborghinis.